# Usage of Openlayers in Django

Tags: javascript, django, openlayers, geojson

It's been few days i'm trying to make Openlayers work with my Django web site.
I'm totally a noob in Web, so I might miss straightforward stuff that I'm not able to understand, yet.

From what I understand, I need to load Openlayers, so for this in my `index.html`,  I've added in the `<head>` this :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
```

Then in the `<body>` I've added the `index.js` where I would like to work with openlayers:

```
<script src="{% static 'index.js'%}"></script>
```

I've copy paste a simple example in the `index.js` and it's been working correctly.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.333333, 48.866667]),
      zoom: 10

    })
});
```

So I have a map centered on Paris. Now I would like to load a `GeoJson` file, thus I need to add a Layer containing the GeoJon. For this I've followed an example [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html).

Here is my first problem I tried to import like this : `import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';`
or like this `import Style from ol.style.Style` bit I got this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
The only solution I found was to `new ol.style.Style(...)` when I needed to use it. Ugly, but working.

So I've delete all the import and used the full path of each class to call the constructors. Until one of them would not work.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector.VectorLayer({
  source: new ol.source.Vector.VectorSource({
    url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    return style;
  }
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: ol.source.Vector.VectorSource is not a constructor

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html

So I'm asking my self why it is not working, and how is it possible to make it less ugly (to use the Imports)

Answer (score 0):

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
```

You can check the OpenLayers 4 examples https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/ for full build syntax